# No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: linux, ovh

I forgot that I wasn’t using SSH Key for that particular VPS and mistakenly added the following line in my VPS sshd_config: “PasswordAuthentication no”

And **restarted the server** through command. Now, I’m unable to login to my OVH VPS as it displays: “**No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)**”

Please, let me know if there is any possible solution to this problem as I have my important website hosted on this server.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get locked out and can no longer use network based access to manage a server (i.e. you firewall or otherwise disable SSH, are the victim of an attack etc.) many VPS providers provide you with  [out-of-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) management access that will work regardless.

You can then either log in on a local console (or boot from a rescue image) and fix what you broke.

https://www.ovh.com/world/g1276.using_kvm_for_vps

Comment: One more issue. I am able to use root credentials using KVM but still, I can't root login via FileZilla or any other FTP program.

Tried creating an SFTP login which works fine on FileZilla too but the issue with root still persists.

Comment: Typically the root account is disabled for remote logins in your sshd_config (a very reasonable default)

Comment: Yeah! Finally, after numerous tries, got it working. Thanks :)